# Syntax Error ; expected but else found (Pascal)

Tags: pascal

Estoy tratando de hacer anidamientos de if en Pascal, pero en todos los programas que trato de hacer me sale el mismo error

> Syntax Error ; expected but else found

Por ejemplo

```
program temperatura;

const

    t=35;
    Hipotermia: real=36;
    Fiebre: real=37.5;
    Hiperpirexia: real=41;
begin

    if (t<=Hipotermia)then
        writeln('El paciente tiene hipotermia');
    else 
        if (t>Hipotermia) and (t<=Fiebre)then
            writeln('El paciente tiene una temperatura normal');
        else
            writeln('El paciente tiene fiebre');
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo de teoría:

En pascal

- todas las sentencias se terminan por `;`. Este es el símbolo que indica al *compilador* que termina una sentencia completa.
- el `if then` y el `if then else` son sentencias *diferentes*. Cada una termina con un `;`.
- el cuándo tienes varias sentencias, el par `begin`/`end` las *agrupan* en un bloque.

En términos prácticos, las siguientes son sentencias válidas en pascal.

```
if x = 1 then
  x := 2;  //acá termina la sentencia if then

//en este caso, para que varias sentencias formen parte del then, 
//las encerramos en begin/end
if x = 1 then
begin
  x := 2;
  y := 3;
end;

if x = 1 then
  x := 2 
else
  x := 3; //hasta acá termina una sentencia if then else completa, no hay ; antes

if x = 1 then
begin
  x := 2;
  y := 3;
end
else
begin
  x := 3; 
  y := 4;
end;
```

Y esta sentencia, va a dar error:

```
if x = 1 then
  x := 2; //este ; termina una sentencia if then completa
else      //este else sería una sentencia nueva, es un error
  x := 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que también debes poner el begin y el end dentro de los if, de este modo:

```
   program temperatura;

    const t=35;

    Hipotermia: real=36;
    Fiebre: real=37.5;
    Hiperpirexia: real=41;

    begin
        if (t<=Hipotermia)then
            begin
                 writeln('El paciente tiene hipotermia');
            end
        else 
            begin
                if (t>Hipotermia) and (t<=Fiebre)then
                    begin
                        writeln('El paciente tiene una temperatura normal');
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        writeln('El paciente tiene fiebre');
                    end
            end
    end.
```

También he visto que algunos le ponen ; al final del último end de los if, si no te funciona, inténtalo ponerlos en el código de arriba.

Saludos y espero te sirva!